# What is the advantage of Raw Notifications over a normal Request to a server?

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

I know where Tile Notification and Toast Notification come in handy, when your app is inactive, but what is the advantage of Raw Notifications over the next line?

```
WebClient( ).DownloadStringAsync( );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raw notifications allow you to *push* custom data on-demand to your application while it's running. `WebClient.DownloadStringAsync` allows you to *pull* data from a server.

Comment: Performance, battery, ease of development. Think of notifications being useful for a server-event (that only the server knows about) whereas webclient is useful for loading data based on a client event (like a user loading a page or pushing a button).

Comment: Right. Silly of me =P Thanks!

Comment: So I get the Raw-over-DownloadAsync now, but even so, why not use a toast message instead of a raw message? 
Because even though the app would be inactive, the user would still get the notification, where a raw would only be submitted if the user is actively using the app?

Comment: @GeekPeek - Raw messages can contain binary data up to 3kb that can be processed in a custom way by the application. Toast push notifications can only include data in the querystring of the page it launches. Raw notifications are quite rare, but they're handy when you need them. Horses for courses.

Answer (score 3):

A raw notification is probably best used *alongside* a pull request in a lot of cases.  I would tend to use a notification purely to tell a running client that  - that could be anything from a new message has arrived server-side (in which case you might want to send out the message in the notification) to "The whole of the data set on the server has been updated, you'd better come along when you can and get the latest changes".

As mentioned, you *can* use the raw notification to send out all the required information if it is small enough, but on other occasions you will most likely just be telling the app that it needs to call home for some action.  Your choice would have to be based on the expected size of the payload.  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402558%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

> The maximum size of a notification is 1 KB for the header and 3 KB for
>   the payload.